# How to move the horizontal slider to particular position using selenium webdriver when attributes(width) given in percentage

Tags: selenium

I am new learner to selenium webdriver.
I want to automate the horizontal slider using selenium webdriver and want to drag it to particular position. I am using method dragAndDropBy(WebElement source, int xOffset, int yOffset) of Actions class.

The problem here i am facing is that the attribute values is given in percentage.
Not getting how to convert and use it using above method.
Please help!!

***html code is***

```
<div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header" style="left: 22.4138%; width: 77.5862%;"></div>
<a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 22.4138%;" data-di-id="di-id-a1aeb2f-f2fcdf16"></a>
```

***Code i created is***

```
WebElement drag=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-slider-range ui-widget-header']"));
Thread.sleep(10000);
//Creating an object for Actions class
Actions a = new Actions(driver);
a.dragAndDropBy(drag, 3, 0).perform();
```

This is not working as i have just tried using any random int value which takes me to the end of slider when executed.

Comment: is there a public url where we can replicate ur issue?

Comment: yes, the url is http://www.asos.com/Women/Dresses/Party-Dresses/Cat/pgecategory.aspx?cid=11057&via=top&r=2#state=Rf-800%3D97%2C-1&parentID=Rf-800&pge=0&pgeSize=36&sort=-1

I want to automate price range slider.